# Как скрыть панельку адреса сайта?

Tags: html, css

тоесть ссылка на сайт добавляется ярлыком на планшет
и после клика открывается сайт

но адрес сайт не должен быть виден. А обычно он всегда показывается

Comment: Не использовать браузер ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Следует указать, о каком браузере идет речь, но в большинстве самых популярных такой опции нет, только если отправлять сайт сразу в fullscreen режим.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью Electron.js можно превратить сайт в программу для PC/Mac